# How to use Hyper body channel?

Tags: http, post, rust, hyper

I am trying to make a POST HTTP request using the Hyper library, and then write data to it until I close it (from multiple functions/threads). I've found in documentation that I can use `Body::channel()` to do this, but I am using it improperly as I can only write to the channel once. I haven't found any examples, can someone please point me into the right direction?

```
let (mut sender, body) = Body::channel();

let request = Request::builder()
    .method(Method::POST)
    .uri("http://localhost:3000/")
    .header("content-type", "text")
    .body(body)
    .unwrap();

let client = Client::new();
let response = client.request(request);

//Does get sent
println!("Body: {:?}", sender.send_data(hyper::body::Bytes::from("test\n")).await);
//Stuck on this one
println!("Body: {:?}", sender.send_data(hyper::body::Bytes::from("test2\n")).await);
//Debug print
println!("{:?}", response.await);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to wrap the [`send_data()`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.14.2/hyper/body/struct.Sender.html#method.send_data) lines in `tokio::spawn(async move { ... });`.

The issue is that [`Body`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.14.2/hyper/body/struct.Body.html)/[`Sender`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.14.2/hyper/body/struct.Sender.html) only has a buffer size of 1. So the second `send_data()` call causes it to `await` (internally) until the `Sender` is ready. This is what subsequently causes it to "get stuck".

This is resolved by using [`tokio::spawn()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.0.1/tokio/fn.spawn.html) as it finally allows `await`ing the [`ResponseFuture`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.14.2/hyper/client/struct.ResponseFuture.html), which causes the request to be performed.

```rust
let (sender, body) = Body::channel();

let request = Request::builder()
    .method(Method::POST)
    .uri("http://localhost:3000/")
    .header("content-type", "text")
    .body(body)
    .unwrap();

let client = Client::new();

let response = client.request(request);

tokio::spawn(async move {
    let mut sender = sender;

    println!("Body: {:?}", sender.send_data(hyper::body::Bytes::from("test\n")).await);
    println!("Body: {:?}", sender.send_data(hyper::body::Bytes::from("test2\n")).await);
});

println!("{:?}", response.await);
```

---

The buffer size isn't mentioned in the docs (that I know of). However, you can figure that out by checking the [source related to `Body::channel()`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.14.2/src/hyper/body/body.rs.html#137-138), where you can see it constructs a MPSC using [`futures_channel::mpsc::channel(0)`](https://docs.rs/futures-channel/0.3.8/futures_channel/mpsc/fn.channel.html). The docs mention that the buffer size would be `buffer + num-senders`, which in our case would be `0 + 1`.